# Failure Callback Whatsapp API Twilio

Tags: twilio, response

[image: Error message]

i've just copied the example of a whatsapp bot in the post to test whatsapp API: https://www.twilio.com/blog/php-twilio-whatsapp

script for Send message is working properly (i'm using sandbox). But the callback is not working. i get the 11200 - HTTP retrieval failure. Someone could analyse my code below? note that i downloaded the SDK not via composer.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;
$guess = $_REQUEST['Body'];
$pick = rand(1,5);

if (!in_array($guess, [1,2,3,4,5])) {
   $response->message("Hiya! I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 5 - try to guess it!");
} elseif ($guess == $pick) {
   $response->message("Yes! You guessed it!");
} else {
   $response->message("Nope, it was actually $pick - Pick a new number to play again!");
}

print $response;
```

Comment: Can you browse locally and is Ngrok URL correct?

Comment: I'm not locally! I'm using my web hosting. I set up the public URL on twilio panel for "use this URL for callback..."

Comment: Does the error message details provide any insights to work through? https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200

Comment: I add the error message in the post above!

Comment: The error says that your server returned a 500 response. Are you able to make a request to it using Postman or curl or even in your browser?

Comment: I'm able to make a request using browser!!